# How to automatically set Angular in production mode when running ASP.NET Core in release mode

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, asp.net-core-mvc

I used the build in template to run Angular in an ASP.NET Core MVC app.
I wonder how I could set the `environment.production` variable of Angular to `true` when running the ASP app in release mode (while using `false` in debug).
This way, I don't have to manually add or remove `enableProdMode()`.

Comment: You can just use `ng serve --prod` to run in production mode and `ng serve` to run in degub

Answer (score 1):

There is this HUGE article on Angular website that talks about deployment. I do recommend reading it (https://angular.io/guide/deployment)

But a TL:DR would be that you can run

```
ng build --prod --build-optimizer
```

For a production code and ng build or ng serve for a debug / development environment

Comment: Yes, the problem seems to be that the `EnvironmentName` property of the `IHostingEnvironment` object in the `Configure` method is set to `Development` even in release mode, so it always call the `ng serve` command. In can't figure out why.

Comment: Ok, my bad, I had to create a new profile. But now the question is: "How to automatically associate each profile to each mode (`Debug` & `Release`)"?

Comment: On your angular.json file you have an object like this:
`"configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],`

You can change the production file there. There are some configuration there for development too

Comment: I'm talking about the `Debug` & `Release` modes used when compiling de project with Visual Studio. How can I associate them with the profile to use (that will define the proper `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` that will then select the right commands to use to compile Angular).